# How to point to an particular folder without redirecting the url in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having an folder called "sample" in my server root at http://www.mydomanin.com/sample/

Under this "sample" folder am having index.php and few other files.

There are few keywords like "oxfordmedical", "simsmedical" etc. when those keywords were there on url, it should point to "sample" folder.

when user navigates to http://www.mydomanin.com/oxfordmedical/, (there is no physical folder exists in the name "oxfordmedical"), it should point to "sample" folder without redirecting, i.e URL should remain same "http://www.mydomanin.com/oxfordmedical/", but index.php file from "sample" folder needs to be called.

how to do this in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} oxfordmedical [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} simsmedical [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sample/ [L]
```

Comment: verified 100% working on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Its not working in my local, but working in server. thanks a lot for your support.
Its needs to be redirected only when exact name was given like
http://www.mydomanin.com/oxfordmedical/.
But now its redirecting even if i give http://www.mydomanin.com/oxfordmedical123/